# Receive SMS from users and store in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mobile, sms, amazon-sns

I gave a requirement involving SMS and AWS platform, the requirement is - users can send SMS to a mobile number and I need to store the SMS and it's metadata into AWS RDS or DynamoDB or any AWS compatible storage. These SMS will be used to populate a realtime dashboard.

Anyone here came across such a scenario? or any tools or technologies I could use to resolve it?

Thanks a ton for your replies,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

You can send the SMS message using [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/). I see you have tagged Python. If you want to use this to send the message, Amazon has provided an AWS SDK called [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The message can be stored by using any RDS-compatible database engine (PostgreSQL, Aurora, MySQL, etc.). Amazon RDS simply provisions the servers that will run this software. If you are planning to make a web app for the dashboard, a framework like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) would be a good choice. Then you could use something like [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the realtime requirement.

Comment: Thank you, I am considering Django for the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, receiving international SMS is free and without hassle on the receiver's side. Unlike sending SMS which AWS SNS provide

So that separate the SMS receiving business and the storage business. To receive SMS you can look at Nexmo or Twilio.

Please note that SMS fails regularly and the sender is charged for international SMS most of the time